# Tkinter Optionmenu not displaying selection

Tags: python, tkinter, optionmenu

I am in the process of creating a product configurator using multiple Optionmenus each dependent on one or multiple of the above choices, but in my second Optionmenu, it either doesn't select or is not displaying the selection once clicked.  I am quite new to python and coding in general so not sure where my problem lies.

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk

def cap_filter(selection):
    options = {
        'Arm': ['50kg', '100kg', '200kg', '300kg'],
        'Arm (Food Grade)': ['75kg'],
        'Rail': ['125kg', '300kg'],
        'Drive': ['125kg', '300kg'],
    }

    if selection in options:
        items = options[selection]
    else:
        items = []
    print(items)

    # remove old elements
    cap_dropdown['menu'].delete(0, 'end')

    # add new items
    for text in items:
        cap_dropdown['menu'].add_command(label=text, command=lambda arg=text:length_filter(arg))


def length_filter(selection):
    type_ = lift_type.get()

    if selection == '50kg' and type_ == 'Arm':
        length_choice = ['3m']
    elif selection == '75kg':
        length_choice = ['4.2m']
    elif selection == '100kg' and type_ == 'Arm':
        length_choice = ['3m', '4m', '5m']
    elif selection == '125kg':
        length_choice = ['N/A']
    elif selection == '200kg' and type_ == 'Arm':
        length_choice = ['3m', '4m', '5m']
    elif selection == '300kg' and type_ == 'Arm':
        length_choice = ['3m', '4m']
    elif selection == '300kg' and type_ == 'Rail':
        length_choice = ['N/A']
    elif selection == '300kg' and type_ == 'Drive':
        length_choice = ['N/A']
    else:
        length_choice = ['N/A']

    print(length_choice)

app = tk.Tk()

lift_type = tk.StringVar()
lift_type.set('Lift Type')
files = ['Arm', 'Arm (Food Grade)', 'Rail', 'Drive']

lift_dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(app, lift_type, *files, command=cap_filter)
lift_dropdown.pack()

lift_cap = tk.StringVar()
lift_cap.set('Capacity')
cap_choice = ['']

cap_dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(app, lift_cap, *cap_choice, command=length_filter)
cap_dropdown.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please reduce your code to the absolute minimum to demonstrate the described problem.

Comment: The text displayed is stored in the StringVar for that OptionMenu. In the command you need to include an update to that. For your second menu add `lift_cap.set(selection)` to the "length_filter" function.

Comment: Novel that worked perfect.  Thanks!

Comment: The above code seems to be working for me. Did you change the code since your original post?  The one thing I notice is that you must make your selection from the first OptionMenu before you get the second OptionMenu populated. This seems correct.